# Need a Solution for pouchDB Database Synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, couchdb, pouchdb

how can I assign the db.get() return value to another variable?

```
doc = db.get(id).then(function(doc) {
    return doc;
}).catch(function(err){
    //errors
})

return doc;
```

The second return is corrupt or undefined.

What would be the proper way to deal with this.

Edit:

after several hours research in this subject, I had to found out this is not possible this way. since it only delivers a promise or a callback, because PouchDB is programmed to be Async.

Is there a way to use it as sync instead of async? As I do understand the benefits, the Sync method offers me more benefits in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isnt possible to use PouchDB synchronously, the underlying API's that it uses (IndexedDB / WebSQL etc) all only have an async API